# How to read single character sequenses and special command sequences?

Tags: deno

I am trying to read individual characters from standard input. According to this issue https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/3614 it does not currently seem possible without the use of an end of file signal such as `ENTER`. Anyone know how I could capture special commands such as `ctrl + c`?

Answer (score 0):

As you have already discovered at the moment it is not possible read a single
character from `Deno.stdin`.

It is however possible with a little overhead to simulate such behavior:
for example a workaround it is to use a process that reads char by char, appends the ENTER char, and pipes into deno.

For example on a linux box with with bash:

```
terminal> ./read1char.sh | deno demo.ts
```

#### read1char.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
   read -n1 varname

   # echo append a newline to input char
   echo "$varname"
done
```

#### demo.ts:

```
async function handle_signal() {
  for await (const _ of Deno.signal(Deno.Signal.SIGINT)) {
    console.log("interrupted!");
  }
}

async function main() {
  const decoder = new TextDecoder();
  const encoder = new TextEncoder();

  const file = Deno.stdin;
  while (true) {
    const c = new Uint8Array(1);
    if (await file.read(c) == Deno.EOF) {
      break;
    }
    const char = decoder.decode(c);
    if (char != "\n") {
      Deno.stdout.write(encoder.encode(char.toUpperCase()));
    }
  }
}

main();
handle_signal();
```

`handle_signal` is a simple signal handler that captures `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 0):

[As of Deno 1.27](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/15796), this is now possible with `Deno.stdin.setRaw(true)`. When stdin is in raw mode, `read()` will not wait for a newline.

Sample code:

```js
Deno.stdin.setRaw(true);
let chunk = new Uint8Array(0);
const reader = Deno.stdin.readable.getReader();
while (true) {
    if (chunk.length === 0) {
        const readResult = await reader.read();
        if (readResult.done) break;
        chunk = readResult.value;
        continue;
    }
    const key = chunk[0];
    chunk = chunk.slice(1);
    console.log(key);
    if (key === 3) break; // ctrl-c
}
```